# ¿Dónde esta el error? Me piden mostrar los números primos dentro de un rango

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n_inicial;
    int n_final;
    int i;
    int a=0;
    int r;

    cout<<"ingrese el numero inicial :";
    cin>>n_inicial;
    cout<<"ingrese el numero final :";
    cin>>n_final;

    r=n_inicial+1;

    for(int i=r;i<n_final;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            if(i%j==0){
                a=a+1;
            }
        }

        if(a==2){
            cout<<i<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Mi código compila pero cuando pongo por ejemplo `n_inicial = 20` y `n_final = 40` solo me imprime un numero y ahí queda.

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene solamente código, no explicas cuál es el comportamiento erróneo que tienes. Te sugiero tomarte el tiempo de explicar qué está haciendo mal tu programa y, si llega a ese punto, coloca un ejemplo de la entrada que le das, la salida que esperas, y la salida actual de programa.

Comment: bueno en si,mi codigo si compila pero ...cuando pongo por ejemplo n_inicial =20 y n_final=40 solo me imprime un numero y ahi queda..

Comment: ¿Has probado [depurar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depurador) el programa paso por paso? Haciéndolo el error está bastante claro.

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que `a` (que es el contador de divisores del número que se está procesando) se inicializa fuera del primer bucle `for`. ¿Qué significa eso? Que el valor de `a` sólo se incrementará con cada número que se procese, y aunque el número sea primo, `a` pasará de valer 2 a valer 2 + el valor que tuviera antes, entonces la comprobación final (`if(a==2)`) siempre fallará.

La solución sería reinicializar el valor de `a` a 0 al principio del bucle `for`:

```
for(int i=r;i<n_final;i++){

    a = 0; // inicializa el valor de a para cada número que se vaya a comprobar

    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
        if(i%j==0){
            a=a+1;
        }

     }
    if(a==2){
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bien señalado el error. Pero hay numerosos fallos de estilo (variables no usadas, no inicializadas, con nombre repetido o con nombre corto) y de algoritmo (comprueba números pares, una vez encontrado el primer divisor sigue contando). En general da la sensación que Ricardo Tovar tiene problemas de comprensión de C++ mucho más graves que el restablecimiento de variables en inicio de bucles. Eso sin contar que si hubiera depurado el código paso-a-paso habría vistu su fallo inmediatamente, lo que hace pensar que ni siquiera lo intentó.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Fallos de estilo y de algoritmo propios de una persona que está aprendiendo y que por lo tanto aún no tendrá unos conocimientos avanzados ni del lenguaje ni de algoritmos. De hecho, esto parece una tarea de Programación I. Intentar algo más avanzado sería contraproducente porque 1) puede que OP no lo entienda, y 2) puede confundir y/o frustrar a OP. En mi opinión lo correcto es limitar la solución a lo solicitado en la pregunta y en un nivel similar al de la pregunta, en lugar de reescribirla y dar algo completamente nuevo, que puede ser perfecto pero lejos del nivel esperado.

Comment: bueno si,soy nuevo en esto mundo. estoy estudiando programacion 1

Comment: @RicardoTovar Por curiosidad, ¿entiendes por qué en la otra respuesta se pone `std::cout` en lugar de `cout`?¿o para qué sirven los `{}` después de las variables?¿O por qué el bucle `for` tiene vacías algunas partes dentro del paréntesis?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema.

Como ya ha señalado [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/25140/2742), tu contador de divisores `a` no restablece su valor a `0` en cada vuelta de bucle; si en tus números de entrada no encuentras un número primo a la primera **jamás** encontrará ningún número primo ya que este contador no parará de aumentar.

> Mi código compila pero cuando pongo por ejemplo `n_inicial = 20` y `n_final = 40` solo me imprime un numero y ahí queda.

Eso no es cierto. He probado tu código y no se comporta así. En la primera vuelta `a` ya no vale `2` al detectar divisores del número `21` y a partir de ahí crece haciendo imposible que jamás obtenga el valor `2` en la primera vuelta requerido para mostrar al menos un número. Podría ser cierto si el número inicial fuese `40` ya que `41` es primo.

---

Tu código tiene una serie de problemas de estilo y algoritmo:

- Estilo.

  1. La variable `i` de `main` no se usa, queda oculta por la variable `i` de tu primer bucle `for`.
  2. Sin contar las variables de los bucles `for` no inicializas más que una variable.
  3. Los nombres de algunas variables son muy cortos y no son auto-explicativos, haciendo difícil entender el código.
- Algoritmo.

  1. Estás comprobando si los números pares son primos, cuando ya sabemos directamente que no lo van a ser.
  2. Una vez encontrado un divisor, sigues recorriendo el bucle, cuando ya sabemos que con al menos un divisor (diferente de `1`) no va a ser primo.

     - Hablando de esto ¿por qué compruebas si es divisible por `1` si ya se sabe que cualquier número entero es divisible por `1`?

#### Propuesta.

Mi aproximación intentaría resolver los problemas listados:

```
int main()
{
    // Tan solo necesitamos las variables inicial y final.
    int n_inicial{}, n_final{};

    std::cout << "\ningrese el numero inicial :";
    std::cin  >> n_inicial;
    std::cout << "\ningrese el numero final :";
    std::cin  >> n_final;
    std::cout << '\n';

    /* Recorremos los numeros del inicial al final pero
    empezamos por el inicial + 1 si inicial es par.
    También avanzamos los números de 2 en 2 para saltar
    los numeros pares. */
    for (int numero { n_inicial % 2 ? n_inicial : n_inicial + 1 }; numero < n_final; numero += 2)
    {
        /* Empezamos intentando dividir entre 3 pues ya sabemos
        que no estamos considerando numeros pares. El bucle se
        interrumpe tan pronto como encuentre un divisor, evitando
        hacer comprobaciones sobre numeros que ya sabemos que no
        seran primos. */
        int divisor{3};
        for (; (divisor < numero) && (numero % divisor); ++divisor);

        /* Llegados a este punto, si el ultimo divisor del numero
        es el propio numero, significa que el numero es primo. */
        if (divisor == numero)
            std::cout << numero << '\n';
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando [[aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mZhSR7ZnIFCli6er). Ten en cuenta que el código anterior no mostrará como primos los números `1` y `2`.